# Recently After we reset and setup laptop through autopilot, when open windows settings, it cannot open settings

Tags: windows-10

Recently after we reset and setup laptop through autopilot, when open Windows settings, it cannot open anything. What I mean is I cannot open Windows update, display settings, any settings inside **Settings** cannot be opened.

Please see the picture to see what I mean. Search e.g. display settings, but it doesn't open/do anything.

Windows settings missing all the icons:

[image: Windows settings missing all the icons]

I tried to do sfc /scannow and dism online cleanup-image restorehealth. I even tried wipe/delete the O.S and reinstall Windows 10 22H2, still got the same problem.

Have anyone seen this before, if so what is the fix please?

Comment: What group policies did you enable?

Comment: By “Reset” what exactly do you mean? Please describe the exact actions you performed.

Comment: Indeed it sounds like some configuration in the [Autopilot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/autopilot/windows-autopilot) might have caused this issue. You mention reinstalling Windows, did you use a custom image/autopilot or a standard/bare/vanilla build? [Someone mentioned this issue is fixed by right-clicking taskbar, Taskbar settings, Taskbar on left](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-settings-is-empty/af6bfa66-e83d-4b21-b70d-502f6e147d4d)

Comment: @gregg We just use an image that download from windows web and then run the setup through Autopilot.

Comment: @gregg the link you send me do not work

Comment: @Ramhound I won't know what group policies  we enable, as I don't work in the server side

Comment: @DanielB Reset this PC > remove everything

Comment: (1) Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). (2)  Open powershell as Admin and run `Get-AppXPackage | foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode – Register "$($_.InstallLocation) \AppXManifest.xml"}`.

Comment: @user3755790 - Ask somebody who does in that case.  At this point it's unclear if this is an image problem or intended behavior due to the applied group policies.  You most certainly could determine which group policies are enabled if you were an Administrator on the AD domain

Comment: @gregg you are right turns out there is a configuration profile group which block control panel/settings

Answer (score 0):

*Copied [my comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1804226/recently-after-we-reset-and-setup-laptop-through-autopilot-when-open-windows-se?noredirect=1#comment2829095_1804226) into an answer as [OP said it lead them to the solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1804226/recently-after-we-reset-and-setup-laptop-through-autopilot-when-open-windows-se?noredirect=1#comment2829139_1804226) so they MAY want to accept this as the answer, I leave it up to them:*

Indeed it sounds like some **configuration in the [Autopilot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/autopilot/windows-autopilot)** might have caused this issue. You mention reinstalling Windows, did you use a custom image/autopilot or a standard/bare/vanilla build? [Someone mentioned this issue is fixed by right-clicking taskbar, Taskbar settings, Taskbar on left](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-settings-is-empty/af6bfa66-e83d-4b21-b70d-502f6e147d4d)